# Securing Elasticsearch on Azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, azure-vm

I've created an Azure VM with an ELK stack (https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/apps/elk). I've changed configuration to be able to connect to ES from another machine (https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/apps/elk/administration/connect-remotely) and opened inbound ports (9200-9300). Tried indexing documents from my localhost- works fine. What i need to do now is to impose a security constraint so that only my Azure AppService application could access ES.

How can I do that? Is there any Azure solution for this? Or do I need to search for ES plugins that handle security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict access to your Elastic VM and give access only to WebApp, do the following:

- Get Outbound IP list from Azure WebApp. Properties -> Additional Outbound IP Addresses
  [image]
- Go to ELastic VM NSG(Network Security group) and create an Inbound rule that allows access to ports 9200-9300. Add IP addresses from the WebApp "Additional Outbound IP Addresses" list
  [image]

Comment: Thank You, that will certainly work for my dev env. But is there more elegant way to do this, e.g. something like using managed identity of an app?

Comment: Unfortunately currently there is no other way to restrict communication other than NSG.
Managed identity won't restrict the traffic to flow, it is intended to create Object in AzureAD and give permissions inside Azure